# Use of | while making declarations in C++

Tags: c++

I came across the following declaration while working on a sample code in C++. Can anyone explain the use "|" while making the declaration?

```
static const DWORD c_FaceFrameFeatures = FaceFrameFeatures::FaceFrameFeatures_BoundingBoxInColorSpace
| FaceFrameFeatures::FaceFrameFeatures_PointsInColorSpace
| FaceFrameFeatures::FaceFrameFeatures_RotationOrientation
| FaceFrameFeatures::FaceFrameFeatures_Happy;
```

Note that DWORD is an alias for unsigned int.
This snippet is taken from the FaceBasicsD2D sample for Kinect V2.

Comment: Binary OR. Used here to combine flag values.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError preferably known as bitwise-or, since binary operators are operators that take 2 operands (see unary and ternary operators).

Comment: There's nothing special about using `|` in a declaration. It's the same as in any other expression.

Comment: @DrewDormann: it's not always *bitwise* OR.  For example the R language uses it for logical OR.

Comment: Your use of `|` represents the [bitwise or](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR) that is used across languages in computer science.

Comment: @Quentin: Thanks - bad use of terminology on my part there - not enough sleep :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have there is the creation of a "bitmask" using several const "enum" values combined using "bitwise OR" (the `|` character).

Typically this is done when several "flags" are desired in a compact, somewhat extensible representation.  Only somewhat extensible because a DWORD is 32 bits so holds at most 32 flags.

Given that the flags usually have values which are all-bits-zero except one bit, you can also simply add them, though this is less conventional:

```
static const DWORD c_FaceFrameFeatures = FaceFrameFeatures::FaceFrameFeatures_BoundingBoxInColorSpace
+ FaceFrameFeatures::FaceFrameFeatures_PointsInColorSpace
+ FaceFrameFeatures::FaceFrameFeatures_RotationOrientation
+ FaceFrameFeatures::FaceFrameFeatures_Happy;
```

Answer (score 3):

**In short: The bitwise OR operator is setting multiple flags at once.**

`c_faceFrameFeatures` is an unsigned int, and each bit of that int is used individually as a flag. So one bit will define whether the option `PointsInColorSpace` is true or false, and another bit will define `RotationOrientation`, and so on. So the intent of this code snippet is to set several flags at once during the declaration.

You could look at the documentation's [list of FaceFrameFeatures flags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.face.faceframefeatures.aspx), and note how each flag is defined as a single bit in hex notation.